# Iterating nested loop and returning matched value is not working in Node.js using lodash module

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have two lists. The first one is a list of values and other is a list of strings where any string can contain these values. So I am iterating over wordList and in inner loop iterating over values, when ever a string contains value it should return the value.

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const valueList = ['abb','bcd','ghi'];

const wordList = ['ab','a','abc','abcde','bcef','aghif'];

const selectedValue = _.filter(wordList, (word) => {
  return _.filter(valueList, (value) => {
    return _.includes(word,value);
  });
});

console.log(`Printing  matched value  ${selectedValue}`);
// Output should be bcd as 'bcd' as wordList contains this value and also it is first match.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't need lodash. Plain JavaScript can do it too:

```js
const valueList = ['abb','bcd','ghi'];

const wordList = ['ab','a','abc','abcde','bcef','aghif'];

const selectedValue = valueList.find( val => wordList.some(word=>word.includes(val)));

console.log(`Printing  matched value  ${selectedValue}`);
// Output should be bcd as 'bcd' as wordList contains this value and also it is first match.
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code using lodash.

```html
const _ = require('lodash');

const valueList = ['abb','bcd','ghi'];

const wordList = ['ab','a','abc','abcde','bcef','aghif'];

const selectedValue = _.filter(valueList, (value) => {
  return _.some(wordList, (word) => {
    return _.includes(word,value);
  });
});

console.log(`Printing  matched value  ${selectedValue}`);
```

Comment: it returns bcd,ghi